# On Site User Testing Software

Tags: windows-7, macos, webcam, screen-capture

Is there any software for OS X or Windows that can capture both the screen and capture the user via cam? I need this for on-site user testing where people sit down and try our app.

Answer (score 0):

We've used [Morae](http://www.techsmith.com/morae.html) in the past with some success. Also just a cheap video cam and screen sharing software work.

Additionally there is this [thread](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8775/usability-testing-software-with-eye-tracking-tools) on the UX site.